# Go: pointer behaviour for a struct type

Tags: go, pointers

This code:

```
y := 7
fmt.Println(y)
fmt.Println(&y)
fmt.Println(*&y)
```

It prints 7, some memory address and 7, as expected.

But this:

```
x := time.Now()
fmt.Println(x)
fmt.Println(&x)
fmt.Println(*&x)
```

It always prints current time.

Shouldn't second Println print some memory address?

Comment: `time.Time` implements [fmt.Stringer](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type that implements `fmt.Stringer` gets func `string()` called on pointer or value. A type that does not gets the memory address printed.

`time.Time` implements `fmt.Stringer`, while int does not.